# How to write trigger on one table to prevent updating data but insert those data into other table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to stop updating data into my bb_tax table and store those data into my tax_change_info table. I wrote this trigger. but nothing inserts into my tax_change_info table if I raise an error. it works without exception but it will update data into my bb_tax which I don't want.
How should I write a trigger to achieve this?

here's my trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_TAX_RATE
BEFORE UPDATE OF taxrate 
ON BB_TAX 
FOR EACH ROW  
DECLARE 
v_user varchar(50);

BEGIN 
    select user into v_user from dual;
    INSERT INTO TAX_CHANGE_INFO VALUES(v_user,:OLD.TAXRATE, :NEW.TAXRATE);
    dbms_output.put_line('insert done');
    
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20505,'You are not allowed to update taxes.');   
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial request was to capture the change attempt and raise an exception to let the user know the request failed. The accepted answer does prevent the update and captures the change attempt but (imho) it is a failure of the worst kind. It does not let the user that the requested change **did not occur**; from the user's viewpoint the update was successful. Any result of using the tax rate afterward does not produce the expected result.  
Now it is true cannot get the initial desired results directly through a trigger. But there is a work around. Create another procedure to Insert the change attempt. Define this procedure as an AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION. This allows you to commit and yet keep it separate from the main transaction. The trigger simply calls this procedure, and on return throws the exception. See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=236009ddd977377f31a23070e6cf81d6).  

**Downside:** If user attempts updating multiple rows the above only captures the 1st as subsequent rows are not processed. To capture all attempted changes you could use a compound trigger and throw the exception in the AFTER STATEMENT section.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I thought the same that it will not let users know that data haven't actually been updated.

Answer (score 4):

When you raise an exception then the operation fails, you cannot have both.
A `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger does not have any `:NEW` value.

If you like to prevent an update, then you could do it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_TAX_RATE
   AFTER UPDATE OF taxrate ON BB_TAX 
   FOR EACH ROW      
BEGIN 
    -- no need for 'select user into v_user from dual;'
    INSERT INTO TAX_CHANGE_INFO VALUES(USER, :OLD.TAXRATE, :NEW.TAXRATE);
    :NEW.TAXRATE := :OLD.TAXRATE;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you the answer. I tried it but it throws error for the statement :NEW.TAXRATE := :OLD.TAXRATE;  "ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"

Comment: I used before trigger and rest it same as yours and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much